# How to calculate the number of shapes detected after thresholding

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, contour

I did color segmentation to my image using java OpenCV and the thresholded image can be shown as image 1 :

[image]

I want to calculate the number of white spot in the threshold image. I worked on the `findcontour()` function and tried to get the count of the white spot. However I failed on that. Please help me. My code is here.

```
Imgproc.findContours(destination, contours, hierarchy,
         Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for(int j=0;j<contours.size();j++){
  sum=sum+contours.size();
}
System.out.println("Sum"+sum);
```

Comment: Please help me soon...

Comment: Can you upload the image you are working with?

Comment: what do you mean with "I was failed on that"?  what was the output? and why is your input image called "destination"

Comment: Did you get any error or wrong output?.

Comment: @JeruLuke this is the image which i am working on.

Comment: @Piglet For this I got the number of contours as 48. However I want to get it as 1. because there is only one big white space, it is just a name only.my input is an output of another image which is caused to the colour segmentation. the presented image here is named as "destination" and that is an image which is generated after colour segmentation.

Comment: For this you have to perform morphological  opening operation

Comment: @JeruLuke can I know the method of doing morphological opening operation?

Comment: @Optimus1072 yes.I get wrong out put. number of shapes=48

Comment: if you only want to detect that 1 large blob you should say so in your question. because in your question you said you wanted to count white spots which are many more than 1 in your image. further you have to somehow tell your computer that you are only interested in the big one. how should it know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeru's answer is correct for this case. If you have a case with bigger noise where morpholigocal operations won't take them out, you can make a cutoff with the contour size, something like

```
for contour in contours
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > minimal_length
```

before counting

Comment: Thank you very much for the instruction :D